# New Instance field syntax

Tags: javascript

In the following `class` which makes use of the new instance field syntax:

```
class Range2 {
    default = 77;
    constructor(from, to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
```

Does this get end up acting the same as:

```
class Range2 {
    constructor(from, to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        default = 77;
    }
```

And do all variables outside a function get hoisted to the top of the class, or how does that work?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Was `Range2(1,2).default` equal to 77?

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a property. And its initialisation happens at the top of the constructor not at the bottom.